# How can I copy a highlighted semantic symbol occurrence wrapped in quotes to the clipboard in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When editing an XML document in VS Code and after I click, for example, inside the quotes of

```xml
<section xml:id="agama-automated-installation-profile">
```

VSCode highlights the `agama-automated-installation-profile` string for me but it is not highlighted as a selection by mouse cursor therefore i cannot copy it by CTRL+C
[image]

Is there a shortcut to copy the snippet to the clipboard easily?

CTRL+C just does not work for this snippet because the real selection is empty and thus the whole line is copied.

Comment: what is colored is done with a decorator (background color), it selects the current word and the same word elsewhere in the file with a different color, use `Ctrl+D` first to select current word. Some decorators highlight the current string content.

Comment: with [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#an-example-select-the-next-string-content) you can select the content of the next string, create a key binding and you can even add a `copyToClipboard` property to immediately copy the selection to clipboard, or only copy to clipboard and not select

Comment: Just hit `Shift+Alt+Right` (Expand Selection) twice to select it all and then copy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> (the command `Expand Selection`) twice to select it all and then copy it, or create a macro to do it in one step (with the built-in command `runCommands`):

```json
{
  "key": "alt+g",  // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "editor.action.smartSelect.expand",
      "editor.action.smartSelect.expand",
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
      "cancelSelection"     
    ]
  }
}
```